# Filtering contents from a webpage and displaying in an Android view

Tags: android, android-layout

Is it possible to render only the desired content in a view in android; the content need to be taken from a url and it has to be tailored. For eg; from [this](http://www.nytimes.com/2013/01/29/us/us-plans-base-for-surveillance-drones-in-northwest-africa.html?hp&_r=0) link, I just need to display the heading and matter of the news.

I do not know whether this is possible at all in Android? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can hide it using javascript.

You must set the webclient and hook the page finish event, then execute javascript to hide the part you don't want to show. something like webview.loadUrl('javascript:$("#div").hide());

- if page don't use the jquery, you will have to do it by plain javascript document.getElementById("divId").style.display = "none";